# Auto-launch Waze when connected to Bluetooth

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to have the Waze app on iPhone automatically launch when I connect to my car BlueTooth?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  You'll need to provide us with more info.  What kind of iPhone, what OS version, what version of Waze, etc.  See [ask] for tips on how to ask questions that have a good chance of being answered correctly.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't script apps to auto-start on iOS.  Perhaps if it's jailbroken you could, but I'm pretty sure that's beyond the scope of what can be supported here.

Comment: Couldn't you use IFTTT or Launch Center Pro to automatically kick-off Waze when you leave a geographical area?

Answer (score -1):

There are apps that do this.  They have an option inside the app that somehow enables this result.

Comment: https://triplogmileage.com/knowledgebase/auto-start-with-bluetooth-2/